# How to add header section in merged Google document via Google Apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to merge 2 Google doc files using their ids. Below is the code snippet I followed.

```
  var docIDs = ['documentID_1', 'documentID_2', 'documentID_3', 'documentID_4'];
  var baseDoc = DocumentApp.openById(docIDs[0]);

  var body = baseDoc.getActiveSection();

  for (var i = 1; i < docIDs.length; ++i) {
    var otherBody = DocumentApp.openById(docIDs[i]).getActiveSection();
    var totalElements = otherBody.getNumChildren();
    for (var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j) {
      var element = otherBody.getChild(j).copy();
      var type = element.getType();
      if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) body.appendParagraph(element);
      else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) body.appendTable(element);
      else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) body.appendListItem(element);
      else throw new Error('Unknown element type: ' + type);
    }
  }
```

The merged document looks fine. But the header and footer section is not added in the merged document. I can see there is a header and footer section in the original document. Someone, please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you're using is only working with certain elements from a document like paragraphs, tables and lists. I made some updates to the script to get the [HeaderSection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/header-section) and [FooterSection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/footer-section)  as well.

You can try the following script:

### UPDATED SCRIPT

```js
function myFunction() {
  var docIDs = ['documentID_1', 'documentID_2'];
  var newDoc = DocumentApp.create('Document Name');//You can change the name of the new document
  var newDocID = newDoc.getId();
  var baseDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newDocID);
  baseDoc.addHeader();
  baseDoc.addFooter();

  var body = baseDoc.getBody();
  var bodyHeader = baseDoc.getHeader();
  var bodyFooter = baseDoc.getFooter();

  for (var i = 0; i < docIDs.length; ++i) {
    var otherBody = DocumentApp.openById(docIDs[i]).getBody();
    var otherHeader = otherBody.getParent();
    var totalEl = otherHeader.getNumChildren();
    var totalElements = otherBody.getNumChildren();

    for (var j=0; j < totalEl; ++j){
      var el = otherHeader.getChild(j).copy()
      var t = el.getType();
      if (t == DocumentApp.ElementType.BODY_SECTION) continue;
      else if (t == DocumentApp.ElementType.HEADER_SECTION){
        var header = otherHeader.getChild(j).asHeaderSection().getText();
        bodyHeader.appendParagraph(header);
      }
      else if (t == DocumentApp.ElementType.FOOTER_SECTION){
        var footer = otherHeader.getChild(j).asFooterSection().getText();
        bodyFooter.appendParagraph(footer);
      }
      else throw new Error('Unknown element type: ' + type);
    }

    for (var k = 0; k < totalElements; ++k) {
      var element = otherBody.getChild(k).copy();
      var type = element.getType();
      if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) body.appendParagraph(element);
      else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) body.appendTable(element);
      else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) body.appendListItem(element);
      else throw new Error('Unknown element type: ' + type);
    }
  }
}
```

I tested the script with Google docs that includes headers/footers and it worked. I'm sure there is a better way to achieve this but at least it can give you an idea on how to work with different elements of a Google Doc.

If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: I foresee one issue with this. If docs 2, 3, and 4 have different headers and footers, the baseDoc will ultimately be set to whatever header/footer is set on doc 4. Headers/Footers are set at the document-level and are applied globally to a document (you can't have multiple headers/footers in one document). So as you iterate over the source docs, you'll just be overwriting headers/footers since you can't set them per page.

Comment: @Lorena Gomez thanks for your help. It worked for me. Can you please help me to merge 2 docs and create a new document with merged contents?

Comment: @Sankar You're welcome, I'm glad to know it worked! You can see the updated script above, now it will create a new Google Doc with the merged content.

Comment: @Lorena Gomez the updated script did not work as expected. On each page, the header section is appended 3 times without original formatting. Could you please check it out?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Document.getHeader(/ .addHeader().](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document)